# Как из формы вытянуть таблицу и поместить ее в другом месте?

Tags: php, html, форма

Есть форма с `json` объектом, в которой находится таблица с классом `description-table` и `span` с классом `price`. Вопрос: как вытащить таблицу и спан из формы, но сохранить привязку, причем так, чтобы они были расположены выше самой формы по структуре документа?

т.е. грубо говоря из .... получить .... и сохранить привязку при этом (данные из таблицы чтобы передавались в форме)

```html
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $variable_products['available_variations'] ) ) ?>">
  <div class="single_variation">
    <span class="price"><span class="amount">260.000&nbsp;руб.</span></span>
  </div>
  <table class="description-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="product-quantity">
          <div class="quantity buttons_added">
            <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="27" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4">
            <span>порц.</span>
            <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus">
            <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--/ .description-table-->
<button type="submit" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple single_add_to_cart_button"><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>
<input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="" />

</form>
```

Comment: что значит "Вытащить" и что за привязка?

Comment: @korytoff дополнил описание

Comment: Вам нужно визуально ее отобразить в другом месте? Тогда юзайте css

Comment: И зачем вам вытаскивать таблицу из формы?

Comment: @korytoff на 2 ваших сообщения подробно ответил ниже. и еще: почему вы удаляете теги - разве `php` здесь в коде не представлен?

Comment: php не относится в вопросу. Если убрать код `PHP` суть не измениться

Comment: @korytoff как не изменится? предлагаете решить вопрос на голом html? так он не решаем без бэкенда и/или скриптов. тот, кто ищет вопросы только по тегу `html` ничего посоветовать не сможет и будет еще 1 висяк..(

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `CSS` для визуального отделения таблицы от формы. Вы форму вообще может начать после `<body>` и закончить перед `</body>`.

`Span` с классом `price` никакого отношения к форме не имеет, куда угодно его можете переместить.

### UPD

Тогда выносите таблицу из формы, а в форме используйте `hidden` инпуты и обновляйте их на `JS` при обновлении в таблице

Comment: один `Css` 100% не прокатит: 1 - блоков с формами на странице много, 2- они динамические, адаптивные и произвольного размера, поэтому те места, где мне нужно их отобразить нужно постоянно пересчитывать с помощью скриптов - хочу снять нагрузку с браузера, т.к. при больших пересчетах скрипты срабатывают полностью правильно менее, чем через раз; 3 - `price` как раз-таки отношение к форме имеет, т.к. за пределами формы пересчет цены производимый из таблицы не проходит.. вот я и в тупике

Comment: @Вася покажите где не проходит пересчёт цены при переносе формы.
Пробовали параметр form=form_id для input?

Comment: @sercxjo в таблице кнопки + и -. а для какого `input`? у меня ведь только `table` и `span`

Comment: @Вася, для тех, которые в `table`